# How to align the calendar with week number as the intermonth-text

Tags: emacs, calendar, org-mode

When I use Emacs calendar/diary with org-mode(however I do not think this is the reason of the problem), I encounter the following problem.

The default calendar is like this:

[image: calendar]

I add the following codes to display week number:

```
(copy-face font-lock-constant-face 'calendar-iso-week-face)
(set-face-attribute 'calendar-iso-week-face nil
                    :height 1)

(setq calendar-intermonth-text
      '(propertize
        (format "%2d"
                (car
                 (calendar-iso-from-absolute
                  (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list month day year)))))
        'font-lock-face 'calendar-iso-week-face))

; Title for week number
(copy-face 'default 'calendar-iso-week-header-face)
(set-face-attribute 'calendar-iso-week-header-face nil
                    :height 0.7)
(setq calendar-intermonth-header
      (propertize "Wk"                  ; or e.g. "KW" in Germany
                  'font-lock-face 'calendar-iso-week-header-face))
```

After inserting these codes, the week numbers can be displayed. However, the alignment is a little bit strange like this:

[image]

The last line of the calendar is not aligned. How to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How about adding the same height and font to the iso-week face as is being used in the rest of the calendar? -- When you do that, it wouldn't be smaller any more, but it would fix your problem I think.  I think trying to keep it small and align with the larger would be problematic, but doable with some additional coding taking into consideration . . . something similar to how linum mode operates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your `height` settings that are causing the problem.  You may wish to try experimenting with the other variables such as:  `calendar-left-margin`, `calendar-column-width`, `calendar-day-header-width`, `calendar-day-digit-width`, `calendar-intermonth-header`, `calendar-intermonth-text`.

NOTE:   For anyone wondering how to highlight Saturday instead of Monday, the function `calendar-generate-month` has a line of code that contains `(if (memq i '(0 6))` -- if `calendar-week-start-day` is changed from `0` to `1`, then it would be necessary to alter the above-code from `0 6` to `5 6`.  Alternatively, the font-lock settings can be trumped by adding new keywords for the days of the week.

```
(setq calendar-week-start-day 1)

(setq calendar-intermonth-text
      '(propertize
        (format "%2d"
                (car
                 (calendar-iso-from-absolute
                  (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list month day year)))))
        'font-lock-face 'font-lock-warning-face))

(setq calendar-intermonth-header
      (propertize "Wk"                  ; or e.g. "KW" in Germany
                  'font-lock-face 'font-lock-keyword-face))
```

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/calendar-example.png))</sub>