# Emacs fill column messing up formatting in org agenda and calendar?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Something is very strange with my wife's Emacs installation (on windows). We think it is as a result of mixing up C-x C-f (open file) with C-x f (set fill column to). The symptom is that the calendar, and the org agenda selection screen, both have really weird formatting now:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymrcnigrvukdyo1/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-02%20at%2016.12.20.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xi2rnnh4e84feyx/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-02%20at%2016.13.15.png

I can't see anything odd in her .emacs, which is below, but I'm not a Windows user.

```
 (custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(appmenu-mode t)
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(emacsw32-max-frames t)
 '(emacsw32-style-frame-title t)
 '(hfyview-quick-print-in-files-menu t)
 '(menuacc-mode t)
 '(noprint-hide-print-in-menus t)
 '(noprint-hide-ps-print-in-menus t)
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("E:\\emacs\\todo.org")))
 '(org-agenda-ndays 7)
 '(org-agenda-show-all-dates t)
 '(org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done t)
 '(org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
 '(org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
 '(ourcomments-ido-ctrl-tab t)
 '(rebind-keys-mode t)
 '(recentf-mode t)
 '(sex-mode t)
 '(tabkey2-mode t)
 '(w32-meta-style (quote w32-lr))
 '(w32shell-shell (quote cmd)))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "SystemWindow" :foreground "SystemWindowText" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 98 :width normal :foundry "outline" :family "Arial")))))
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Here is a link to a related issue where the `:height` is what was causing the problems with the calendar alignment:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21367291/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the family to "Arial" is causing the issues, I am not sure why. But removing it worked for me. So if font family is not important to you removing `:family "Arial"` from `custom-set-faces` would fix the problems (you will need to restart emacs)

Comment: Arial is not a monospace font. The format of calendar depends on the font being monospaced - only with monospace will the columns line up one above the other!